# Enforce Full Stop at the end of each Hanging Caption

Tags: formatting, captions

I am trying to enforce a full stop at the end of each caption in my LaTeX document. I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334728/insert-a-period-full-stop-if-caption-argument-doesnt-end-with-one) with basically the same question, but it breaks when using `\usepackage{caption}` as well as hanging captions.

So my goal is to

1. Append "." after each caption (when it doesn't already end with a full stop)
2. Make it work with hanging captions

I tried different things like redefining the `\caption` command. The closest I could get was by copy-pasting the original `hang` caption declaration from gitlab and adding the fullstop manually. Note that I'm using "ABC" to emphasise it even further - at the end I can simply replace that with `\@addpunkt{.}`. The issue with this solution is, that it writes the "ABC" into a new line which is of course not what I am looking for.

```
\usepackage{caption} % Use Caption Package
\usepackage{amsthm} % Adds a fullstop at the end of each caption automatically (if there is none)

\makeatletter
% Copied and adapted from "https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/blob/master/source/caption3.dtx"
% Custom caption format based on the original hang format with "ABC" appended
\DeclareCaptionFormat{customhang}{%
  \caption@iflabelseparatorwithnewline
    {\caption@Error{%
       The option `labelsep=\caption@labelsep@name' does not work\MessageBreak
       with `format=customhang'}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#1#2}%
     \advance\caption@parindent\hangindent\relax
     \advance\caption@hangindent\hangindent\relax
     \caption@@par#3ABC\par}} % "ABC" is just a placeholder for "\@addpunct{.}"
\makeatother
\captionsetup{format=customhang}
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Necessary if you are dealing with figures

\usepackage{amsthm} % Adds a fullstop at the end of each caption automatically (if there is none)
\usepackage{caption} % Use Caption Package
\usepackage{xltabular}  % For captions within xltabular testing

\makeatletter
% Custom caption format based on the original hang format with "ABC" appended
\DeclareCaptionFormat{customhang}{%
  \caption@iflabelseparatorwithnewline
    {\caption@Error{%
       The option `labelsep=\caption@labelsep@name' does not work\MessageBreak
       with `format=customhang'}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#1#2}%
     \advance\caption@parindent\hangindent\relax
     \advance\caption@hangindent\hangindent\relax
     \caption@@par#3ABC\par}} % "ABC" is just a placeholder for "\@addpunct{.}"
\makeatother
\captionsetup{format=customhang}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{This is an example caption}
    \caption{Another sample with a very long caption and we hope that it will properly break into the next line with proper hanging...}
\end{figure}
```

Do you have any suggestions, or can I maybe achieve this even simpler? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `#3` in `\DeclareCaptionFormat` refers to a quite complicated set of tokens that *contains* the caption text, but embedded in several commands.

My suggestion is to redefine `\caption` to pass a final `\@addpunct{.}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Necessary if you are dealing with figures

\usepackage{amsthm} % Adds a fullstop at the end of each caption automatically (if there is none)
\usepackage{caption} % Use Caption Package

\makeatletter
% Custom caption format based on the original hang format with "ABC" appended
\DeclareCaptionFormat{customhang}{%
  \caption@iflabelseparatorwithnewline
    {\caption@Error{%
       The option `labelsep=\caption@labelsep@name' does not work\MessageBreak
       with `format=customhang'}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#1#2}%
     \advance\caption@parindent\hangindent\relax
     \advance\caption@hangindent\hangindent\relax
     \caption@@par#3}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\HIGHNOONcaption}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \CAPTIONcaption*[#2\@addpunct{.}]{#3\@addpunct{.}}%
  }{%
    \CAPTIONcaption[#2\@addpunct{.}]{#3\@addpunct{.}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\captionsetup{format=customhang}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\CAPTIONcaption\caption
  \RenewCommandCopy\caption\HIGHNOONcaption
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics{example-image} % we don't really need it for the example
    \caption{This is an example caption}
    \caption{Another sample with a very long caption and we hope 
      that it will properly break into the next line with proper hanging.}
    \caption{Another sample with a very long caption and we hope 
      that it will properly break into the next line with proper hanging\dots}
    \caption{Another sample with a very long caption and we hope 
      that it will properly break into the next line with proper hanging?}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Omg thats so clever, thank you very much! That also properly deals with `captionof`, right? (at least as far as I can tell)

Comment: Sorry, one quick follow-up: It doesn't seem to work when using it inside xltabular, which is quite weird from my POV? I've added this to the MWE of the above.

Comment: @Highnoon Well, `xltabular` wants to change the meaning of `\caption` and obviously conflicts arise. Please, never change the question to invalidate existing answers: if you have new problems, open a new topic.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolute right. I'll do it, sorry!