# Enforcing Full Stop at the End of Hanging Captions within `xltabular`

Tags: formatting, captions

The [following posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701370/enforce-full-stop-at-the-end-of-each-hanging-caption) provides a solution for adding a full stop at the end of hanging captions, but I'm encountering issues when applying this in the context of `xltabular`.

Can I extend this functionality to also work for captions in `xltabular`? I would love to get help!

Below is a minimal working example (MWE). It demonstrates the successful implementation of adding a full stop to hanging captions but also illustrates the issue with xltabular table captions where the full stop is not being added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} % Adds a full stop at the end of each caption automatically (if there is none)
\usepackage{caption}   % Use 'caption' Package
\usepackage{xltabular} % Load 'xltabular' package

\makeatletter
% Custom caption format based on the original hang format with "ABC" appended
\DeclareCaptionFormat{customhang}{%
  \caption@iflabelseparatorwithnewline
    {\caption@Error{%
       The option `labelsep=\caption@labelsep@name' does not work\MessageBreak
       with `format=customhang'}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#1#2}%
     \advance\caption@parindent\hangindent\relax
     \advance\caption@hangindent\hangindent\relax
     \caption@@par#3}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CUSTOMcaption}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \CAPTIONcaption*[#2\@addpunct{.}]{#3\@addpunct{.}}%
  }{%
    \CAPTIONcaption[#2\@addpunct{.}]{#3\@addpunct{.}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\captionsetup{format=customhang}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\CAPTIONcaption\caption
  \RenewCommandCopy\caption\CUSTOMcaption
}

\begin{document}

% ACTUAL ISSUE OCCURS HERE
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{X}
    DEMO \\
    \caption{Samle with xltabular} % Here a full stop should be added, but currently is not being added!
\end{xltabular}


% Just to ensure that the new solution also works with normal captions inside figures:
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{This is an example caption}
    \caption{Another sample with a very long caption and we hope that it will properly break into the next line with proper hanging...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the desired fixed apply only to "hanging" captions in your document, or should it apply to *all* captions? Please clarify.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the instruction `\usepackage{xltabular}` in the preamble to make the sample compilable. Feel free to revert.

Comment: I'm definitely just using hanging captions - so if it makes things easier, then it's sufficient to work _only_ with hanging captions. And thanks for the edit!

Comment: Would you be ok with a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Or do you have to use pdfLaTeX to compile your documents?

Comment: Sadly I have to use pdfLaTeX :/